# CSS3 background opacity with background image

Tags: css, background-image, opacity

I am attempting to have an opacity effect on my div which has a background-image applied, and still keep the text "un-opacified".
My markup:

```
<div id="projects" class="feature">
    Projects
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.feature {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}

.feature:after {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}

.feature#projects {
    background-image: url('img/hero.png');
}
```

I thought of using pseudo elements, but to no avail!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might use a semi-transparent `png` for the background image, then style the text accordingly.

You might also want to look into RGBa:

http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

This applies to background-color, although it may also work on your image (untested, though)

Comment: @benhowdle89... the RGBa,, right?  How about the semi-transparent `png`.  Not ideal but should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is sort of a hack for it where you layout the div with the background underneath another div containing the text.

Check out the following link:

http://www.sumobaby.net/news/2011/03/04/change-background-opacity-without-affecting-text/

Also here's a quick working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7pVGM/

Note: the markup and css isn't that great I just wrote it in like 5 min :)